# SSIS Data Flow Task doesn't load all rows from OLE DB

Tags: oracle, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to load a table from SQL Server using the Microsoft OLE DB Provider into an Oracle table (using the Oracle Provider for OLE DB). The package is a straight forward OLE DB Source (SQL Server) -> OLE DB Destination (Oracle).

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Oracle 11g.

Every time I run the package, I get a different number of rows in the destination table, and BIDS reports fewer rows read than there are in the source table. The number of rows returned is **different** each time I run it. I get no errors or kickouts, but the boxes for the source and destination remain yellow even after BIDS says "Package completed successfully".

Dumping the source table into a flat file instead of the Oracle destination works fine, and I get all the rows that I expect. I can use this flat file to pull the information into the Oracle destination table without problems as well.

Even though I have a work-around, I want to understand why this is happening, and what I can do to resolve this problem without having to use flat files.

**Edit:** Looks like even using the flat file to Oracle doesn't bring over all the rows. The first time was just luck?

**Edit/Update:** Running the package out of Integration Services (not BIDS) seems to have eliminated the problem (tested three times). Still don't understand why this is happening though.

Comment: Could the variance in initial row counts be tied to changes in the source system? Not trying to be difficult, I just haven't had your experience with SSIS so trying to eliminate the easy ones before I go for esoteric reasons.

Comment: No, this is a table on test, so no one changes it. I've also made sure that the table row count in the source hasn't changed on me.

Comment: The fact that the source and destinations remain yellow would seem to indicate that they haven't actually completed. How many rows are in the source table. Is it very large? Also have you put a viewer on the data flow to see what rows are being transferred?

Comment: The source table has around 480k rows. Due to the size, it's quite difficult to use the viewer to determine which rows aren't coming through (and that a different number of rows are coming through suggests it's not strictly a data issue). In BIDS, the "Package Execution Completed" message popped up, even with the boxes still yellow.

Comment: I've seen packages fail that still show yellow but on the results tab there's an error indicated and the package execution has completed. Any chance that's the case?

Comment: I don't recall any errors showing up, but due to the time constraints I have right now, I can't pull it up to make sure. I will do so as soon as I can.

Comment: I found the Oracle OLE DB drivers to be quite unreliable and have switched to the Attunity Oracle drivers.  This seems to have resolved the flakiness issues and also improved performance.

Comment: I have the same problem. My source DB is Sybase. But in my case the number of rows is always the same every time I run the package.